# Sending custom data attributes from an anchor in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to grab data-fields from my anchor when clicked. I can't seem to make it work with

```
$('.class').on('click',function(){$(this).attr('data-id')});
```

I have no idea why the above doesn't work so instead, I'm doing this instead

```
<a href="#" data-piID="1" onclick="galleryEdit(this); return false;"><i class="icon icon-edit"></i></a>

function galleryEdit(e){$(e).attr('data-id')});
```

How do I send my data-attributes from the anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check your code there is some mistake, so please use this code. this will works for you.

1. In your javascript code have syntax error. there is UN-neccessary ***)*** bracket.
2. Your data attribute element name is wrong.

```js
function galleryEdit(e)
{
console.log($(e).attr('data-piID'));
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-piID="1" onclick="galleryEdit(this); return false;"><i class="icon icon-edit"></i>sandeep</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues here. First, are you assigning the returned value from the call to `$(e).attr('data-id')`? Second, you should use .data instead `$(e).data('id')`

Comment: I get an 'undefined' returned. I tried this:  function galleryEdit(e){
  var piID = $(e).data('data-piID');
  console.log(piID)
 } and also removed the 'data-' on that and nothing

Comment: If you are using `.data(..)` then remove the `data-` prefix. See my example showingthe difference between the call to `.attr(..)` and `.data(..)`

Comment: I actually did that, same error. Also, it's not always gonna be data-id... it might be data-description, etc..